# Flexbox Nav Menus

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a nav menu with a single (or more) item pinned to the left.

I have tried using `align-self: flex-start;` but it won't budge unless `flex: 1;` is set in which case the item fills all remaining space, which I do not want.

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li class="left">1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I want this:

```
| [ 1 ]            [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] |
```

or

```
| [ 1 ] [ 2 ]            [ 3 ] [ 4 ] |
```

Not:

```
| [ 1            ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] |
```

or

```
| [ 1 ] [ 2            ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] |
```

The effect I want would be applied with a class `left` as all items are `justify-content: flex-end;` currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to add `margin-left:auto;` to your first right-aligned element. This will push that element and all the next elements to the right.

```css
nav {
    background:#d8d8d8;
    display:flex;
    padding:1px;
}

a {
    background:white;
    margin-right:1px;
    padding:3px;
}
a.start_right { margin-left:auto; } 
a:last-child { margin-right:0; }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href='#'>Link 1</a>
    <a href='#' class='start_right'>Link 2</a>
    <a href='#'>Link 3</a>
    <a href='#'>Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this the only way possible though? Surely `align-self` should work shouldn't it? (without the block display via flex: 1).

Comment: This is the only way.

Comment: I guess `align-self` can't be used to counter `justify-content` then, seems a bit silly to me.